# Form not posting after user keys in "

Tags: php, forms

I have a 3 step PHP form.

Page1.php - Some details, Page2.php - Summary of page 1 form, with more items and finally email.php - Sends the email of all information keyed in.

On one of the text inputs in Page 1, I could write "Blah Blah Blah" and the Page2.php will have it written in the summary thanks to post. Upon clicking submit on page2.php, thanks to a hidden input, the "Blah Blah Blah" that I entered in Page1, will be sent to me in an Email.

However something odd happens when I type the INCH ("). For example in page1.php I key in "I got a 40" TV" On page2.php it will say "I got a 40" TV" but I will recieve an email saying "I got a 40". The text after the " disappears.

Any idea why?

Comment: You probably have to escape your double quote. But post your code if you want we help us more.

Comment: Likely something is not escaped properly. Post your code. What version of PHP? (I hope magic quotes is not on.)

Comment: I bet it's insufficient escaping when you put the string into the hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you haven't properly escaped the value when you put it into the hidden input field. I expect your code looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['field1']; ?>">
```

If there was a double quote in there you'll end up with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="A 40" TV">
```

See how `value` ends in the middle, too early. The HTML is broken.

You need to escape it, such as with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['field1']); ?>">
```

Then you'll end up with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="A 40&quot; TV">
```